# serializing the POST array to be able to pass lots of data through a link

Tags: php, html, forms, zen-cart

I'm having a noobie problem getting my head round how I can make this work.

I have a page listing products from my DB. On that page there is a filter form which POSTs lots of data to refine the product listing, ie how many results per-page, sort order, pricefrom, priceto plus an array of subcategories

I also have a paging system which is just the standard zencart (`splitpageresults::dsplaylinks` incase anyone is familiar) paging system which shows links for the next, previous and some page numbers. Normally it would pass params as `$_GET` at the end of the links but I have all these fancy filters I've made.

My idea is to serialize the `$_POST` array and send it as a `$_GET` param in the links:

```
<a href="index.php&arr=<?php echo serialize($_POST[]);?>">nxt</a>
```

but is this seems bad all the serializing and unserializing.

What's the best way of doing this?

I can't figure it out!

Comment: Better to save the filters in session. There is a limit on the amount of data that can be passed through url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the `[]` and `urlencode()` the serialized data:

```
<a href="index.php&arr=<?php echo urlencode(serialize($_POST));?>">nxt</a>
```

But you better use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php).

Comment: Thanks, good idea, I've never used them before so never thought!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the advanced search and advanced search result pages for examples of handling a lot of data using POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   /* View.php*/

    $image_arr=array("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg");
    $serial_arr=urlencode(base64_encode(serialize($image_arr)));

    echo '<a href="process.php?arr='.$serial_arr.'">Link</a>';



    /* process.php */
    $image_arr=unserialize(base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['arr'])));

    foreach($image_arr as $value){
       /* do anything here 
        * just as an example
        * https://gist.github.com/vdite/30644e28301916789ff5
        */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO serialize() and deserialize() on $_GET or $_POST is far from being a good idea, there are two main aspects I can think of:

1. Security
2. Best practice

For more details on the security aspect, check out Stefen Esser's OWASP presentation, page 27 on [[PDF, owasp.org]](https://www.owasp.org/images/f/f6/POC2009-ShockingNewsInPHPExploitation.pdf). Generally, not as dramatic as many people want us to believe, but can turn up to be a nasty security issue nevertheless (like phpBB2, Zend, etc).

Best practice would be to use JSONs (json_encode and json_decode are the better option). With JSONs you can do more standards-based AJAX-ing, plus user-friendly JavaScript or jQuery-based pagination or filters.